# Getting current unixtimestamp using Moment.js

Tags: unix-timestamp, momentjs

I want to get the Unix TimeStamp using Moment.js.
I can find many functions which convert timestamp to date in moment.js.
I know that I can easily get the unix timestamp by using the following JavaScript function: `Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)`.

But I want to use Moment.js to get the same result.
Is there any direct function in moment.js to get the current timestamp?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

To find the Unix Timestamp in seconds:

```
moment().unix()
```

The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) is your friend. :)

Comment: @climbinghobo if you want in milliseconds use `moment().valueOf()`

Comment: Not valid anymore. See @kumar chandraketu answer below.

Comment: This will give the time since the epoch, and will not convert the present time to milliseconds

Answer (score 156):

For anyone who finds this page looking for UNIX timestamp w/ milliseconds, [the documentation says](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)

```
moment().valueOf()
```

or

```
+moment();
```

you *can* also get it through `moment().format('x')` (or `.format('X')` [*capital X*] for unix seconds with decimal milliseconds), but that will give you a string. Which moment.js won't actually parse back afterwards, unless you convert/cast it back to a number first.

**NOTE:** This answer continues to get +1s, which is nice, but Moment has been deprecated, and alternatives like `Luxon` or `date-fns` are suggested. See: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status

Comment: Very nice, but the last one (`+moment()`) looks pretty risky!

Comment: @JRichardsz that seems like an unnecessary parsing step, since the first two I mentioned will give you the correct value as a Number.

Comment: Correct. From the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/):

`moment().valueOf();`

or

`+moment();`

Comment: @mix3d I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

for UNIX time-stamp in milliseconds

`moment().format('x') // lowerCase x`

for UNIX time-stamp in seconds 
`moment().format('X') // capital X`

Comment: Note: these will give you the value as a string, and not Number objects.

Answer (score 23):

Try any of these

```
valof = moment().valueOf();            // xxxxxxxxxxxxx
getTime = moment().toDate().getTime(); // xxxxxxxxxxxxx
unixTime =  moment().unix();           // xxxxxxxxxx
formatTimex =  moment().format('x');   // xxxxxxxxxx
unixFormatX = moment().format('X');    // xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: `formatTimex =  moment().format('x');` actually includes milliseconds. So it should be `// xxxxxxxxxxxxx`