# Get current unix time in milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi this is incredibly simple i cant believe im asking this.

I have tried the following:

```
Moment.now()
Date.now()
new Date().valueOf()
```

And various other tricks found in other stack overflow questions

They all give me the time in microseconds.

e.g

```
1543409290654

which is 09/10/50878 @ 10:57am (UTC)
```

Im aware i could divide by 1000 but surely there is an api in javascript to get the unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Ive have seen this in chrome and react native

EDIT:

So i realise my stupidity i was putting the unix timestamp into a website that renders it as an ISO date but it was expecting seconds which is why i thought my dates were coming in as milliseconds

Comment: What is the desired output you are looking for? and what are you actually getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current unixtimestamp using Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499191/getting-current-unixtimestamp-using-moment-js)

Comment: `Im aware i could divide by 1000`  There is your answer, are you having trouble dividing by 1000?.

Comment: console.log(Date.now()) returns 1543409203060 this is not a unix millisconds timestamp. its microseconds

Comment: `ITS NOT working, please read my question`  I think everyone appears to have read the question, but you seem to be ignoring them.  Your still not dividing by 1000, and wonder why it's wrong.  `(new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0)`  ps. Avoid ITS NOT working, it's not helpful.

Comment: As others have pointed out the docs say these apis should return a unix timestamp in milliseconds. How is dividing by 1000 solution. Obviously something else is wrong

Comment: Because the unix time your after is in seconds, not milliseconds.  AKA, why you want to divide by 1000.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970

Comment: If i go into the console and do       console.log(Date.now()) i get 1543409203060 this is not milliseconds since epoch

Comment: in unix the number of seconds since 1Jan 1970 is 1543410557 (as of this moment), so that looks like milliseconds to me. microseconds=1 millionth of a second, milliseconds being 1 thousandth of a second. so 3 digits more than the seconds value.

Comment: ok Im dumb i was putting the timestamp into a website to render it and  that was causing the  confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

There is no native javascript to format time into unix-timestamp.

I found [this](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/unix-timestamp-javascript/) useful

```js
var today = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

console.log(today);
```