# Timestamp convert using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp, momentjs

Hi I'm current trying to convert a timestamp into MM:SS or just into second using momentjs. The format of the timestamp looks like `"2021-02-13T23:56:03.887386+00:00"`. Im pretty new to momentjs, I'm wondering if there is anyway to convert this timestamp into minutes:seconds or just into seconds. I tried using `moment("2021-02-13T23:56:03.887386+00:00").valueOf()`, this gave me a value of `1613260563887`, Im not sure what is this value is. Can anyone please explain this a little bit? Much appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate what value you would expect to see when you "convert a timestamp into MM:SS."  I.e., what is the original timestamp you wish to "convert," and what would the converted output look like?

Comment: So is it possible to convert `"2021-02-13T23:56:03.887386+00:00"` into "56:03" something like that?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `moment("2021-02-13T23:56:03.887386+00:00").format("mm:ss")` to show only the minute and seconds.

As mentioned by @cbr see [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for more formatting details

Comment: I see thanks a lot, do you know what the output value from `moment("2021-02-13T23:56:03.887386+00:00").valueOf()` means? the output is `1613260563887`, is this epoch time?

Comment: It gives oyu the unix time see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moment-js-moment-valueof-function/ Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25509485/3161811